# Помогите решить задачку с thumbnails!

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Был шаблон блога на WordPress. Нужно было сделать чтоб превью новости не кропалось, нашел сделал, изменив array на false.

```
    td_api_thumb::add('td_324x235',
        array(
            'name' => 'td_324x235',
            'width' => 324,
            'height' => 235,
            'crop' => false ,
            'post_format_icon_size' => 'normal',
            'used_on' => array(
                'Module 3, 4, 5, 11, MX3', 'Block 1, 5, 6, 13, 17, 20'
            ),
            'no_image_path' => td_global::$get_template_directory_uri,
        )
```

Найти было нелегко так как тема заковыристая, но в документации шаблона нашел название нужного файла.

Далее происходит странная вещь. Загружаемые на миниатюру квадратные изображения показываются уменьшенно и не во всю ширину контейнера.
При этом были некоторые картинки квадратные которые легли нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменения в стандартных настройках медиафайлов результатов не дают, даже после чистки кеша. 
Далее я попробовал плагин Regenerate Thumbnails  и после него даже те, которые легли нормально, стали уменьшенными.

Я открыл код страницы через браузер, и там есть такая строка:

```
<img width="235" height="235" class="entry-thumb td-animation-stack-type0-2" src=...
```

Когда меняешь в ней значение img wight на нужную ширину, картинка увеличивается и встает как нужно.

```
<img width="234" height="235" class="entry-thumb td-animation-stack-type0-2" src=...
```

Я попробовал найти все это в том же php, где менял кропы но ничего не нашел, в functions темы тоже, в настройках самого WordPress тоже менял, кропал миниатюры, ничего не вышло. Помогите решить это проблему пожалуйста. Спасибо.

сайт: thehaze.ru

Comment: Настрой через CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо замены `array` на `false`, поставьте в нем желаемый размер `thumbnails`, в `width` и `height`. После этого при загрузке новых картинок будет создаваться дополнительно миниатюра нужного вам размера. Чтобы добавить миниатюры заданного нового размера к старым картинкам, нужно запустить Regenerate Thumbnails.